# How to filter non-related object by query

Tags: soql, filters

I have two non-related objects, `Product` and `Lead` and they have 3 matching fields with picklist type. I want to query product whose field 1 = field 1 of lead

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done in a query.

SOQL does not allow fields to appear on the right-hand side of a filterexpression (i.e. `WHERE Field1_c = Field2__c`).

Even if it were possible, you wouldn't be able to handle this with only a single query because the two SObjects you're working with are not related.

You'll need to execute two separate queries, and correlate the results yourself using Apex.

Comment: When two SObjects are related, or if you're trying to compare two fields within a single SObject, the normal workaround is to use a formula field to do the comparison (then add a `MyFormula__c = true` to the `WHERE` clause). Since your two SObjects are not related, this is not an option for you either.